# libcurl ca bundle included in binary

Tags: c++, curl, libcurl

I have an application which statically linked with all dependent libraries and at the end I have a single binary file for Windows and Linux.
Is there a way to set ca certificate at compile time the content wil be included together with binary and it will not be necessary to move it together with application binary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If you use the native SSL library on Windows (sometimes referred to as winssl), there's no need to ship any CA cert at all since curl will then use the internal one Windows features.
2. If you built libcurl to use OpenSSL, you can set a callback to verify the CA with a fixed built-in CA store. Showed in the [cacertinmem](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/cacertinmem.html) example on the curl web site using the [CURLOPT_SSL_CTX_FUNCTION](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_SSL_CTX_FUNCTION.html) option.
3. Shipping an app with a fixed internal CA cert storage might be troublesome when the services your app are using update/change their certs along the way, so maybe using an external file that you can [update occasionally](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html) is still a better idea?